# Meteor show / hide element on button click

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a template like so:

```
<template name="Menus">
  <button class="btn_create new_menu_toggle"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Create a new menu</button>
  <button class="btn_cancel new_menu_toggle"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Cancel</button>
  {{> NewMenu}}
</template>
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is that initially only the `btn_create` is shown. If `.btn_create` is pressed, the `{{> NewMenu}}` is rendered and the `.btn_create` is replaced with `btn_deny`. Vice versa for the behaviour of `btn_deny`.

How would I go about doing this in Meteor I know I could probably accomplish this by adding / changing classes in vanilla Javascript, but I'd like to know if there's an easier method using Meteor / Blaze.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple pattern is to use a session variable to track the state

html:

```
<template name="Menus">
{{#if createMode}}
  <button class="btn_create new_menu_toggle"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Create a new menu</button>
  {{> NewMenu}}
{{else}}
  <button class="btn_cancel new_menu_toggle"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Cancel</button>
{{/if}}
</template>
```

In your javascript you need to set up some event handlers to toggle the state:

```
Template.Menus.events({
  'click .btn_create'(ev){
    session.set('createMode',true);
  },
  'click .btn_cancel'(ev){
    session.set('createMode',false);
  }
});
```

When the template is rendered you need to initialize the session variable:

```
Template.Menus.onRendered(function(){
  session.set('createMode',true);
});
```

Finally you need the helper your template can use for the spacebars conditional expression:

```
Template.Menus.helpers({
  createMode(){
    return session.get('createMode');
  }
});
```